# How to import all photos from gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an app in which right now the user has to select some photos from their gallery with the `onClick` function of a `button` using `intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

Is there a way to get all the images in the user's gallery with just the press of the button?

Comment: Query the `MediaStore`.

Comment: Just add a for-loop, and get all the photos from the device. Even tho this will not work on higher versions of android. But, for consideration of older devices, this was needed to be mentioned. And, there are a lot of tutorial online on youtube where you can find this!